# How to click on a button on a webpage using <td> and <tr>?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to click o the first "Completed" button in the highlighted part of the webpage below.
[image]

Here is a piece of the VBA code of the website page:
[image]

I tried to click on the **FIRST** completed button in many different ways such as :

```
    For Each element In ie3.getElementsByTagName("main_table_data_right_border main_table_data_bottom_border")(5)
  If element.innerText = "Completed" Then
  ' Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:03:00"))
    element.Click
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))
      Exit For
        Else
    End If
Next
```

Or

```
doc.querySelector("#divPage > table.advancedSearch_table > tbody"). _ getElementsByTagName("tr")(3).getElementsByTagName("td")(5).Children(0).Click
```

But none of them seem to work. When I debug the code and I go through this part and this particular line, nothing really happens. So the button is not being clicked.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I already inserted element.Click @arunv. Sorry i did not really understand what do you mean

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `getElementsByTagName` method to find the hyperlink. Please refer to the following sample:

VBA code to find the hyperlink and click the button (in this sample, I just find the special cell in the first row. If you want to loop through the hyperlink, you need to use `For Each` statement to loop through the array).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim Rank As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("http://localhost:54382/HtmlPage47.html")
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
            Exit Do
        Else
        End If
    Loop
    
    Set doc = ie.document
    
    doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(5).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
    
End Sub
```

Code in the Web page:

```
<div>
    <table class="main_table" style="text-align:center;">
        <tr class="main_table_header">
            <td></td>
            <td>Export Type</td>
            <td>Criteria</td>
            <td>Rep./List</td>
            <td>Creation Date</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Reference</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="main_table_data">
            <td>
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>Activites</td>
            <td>Process Date from 2019/07/02 to 2019/07/02</td>
            <td>For an advanced search</td>
            <td>2019/07/03</td>
            <td><a onclick="javascript:alert('hello AA')" id="link1" href="#">Conpleted</a> (601 lines)</td>
            <td>662602308</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="main_table_data">
            <td>
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>Activites</td>
            <td>Process Date from 2019/07/02 to 2019/07/02</td>
            <td>For an advanced search</td>
            <td>2019/07/03</td>
            <td><a onclick="javascript:alert('hello BB')" href="#">Conpleted</a> (601 lines)</td>
            <td>662602308</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="main_table_data">
            <td>
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>Activites</td>
            <td>Process Date from 2019/07/02 to 2019/07/02</td>
            <td>For an advanced search</td>
            <td>2019/07/03</td>
            <td><a onclick="javascript:alert('hello CC')" href="#">Conpleted</a> (601 lines)</td>
            <td>662602308</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="main_table_data">
            <td>
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>Activites</td>
            <td>Process Date from 2019/07/02 to 2019/07/02</td>
            <td>For an advanced search</td>
            <td>2019/07/03</td>
            <td><a onclick="javascript:alert('hello DD')" href="#">Conpleted</a> (601 lines)</td>
            <td>662602308</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, once you click on completed hyperlink, JavaScript gets executed and it opens an Excel file, here you can use `ie3.Navigate "javascript:openExcelFile('t83_Kerrfinancialadvisorsinc/455X3/ExportActivity_66260230820190703122002139.xlsx)"`

Since it's tied with a hyperlink, you can also try using

```
element.Click
element.FireEvent ("onclick")
```

or you can use `execScript`

```
Call ie3.document.parentWindow.execScript("your script in webpage", "JavaScript")
```

Comment: I cannot use the javascript javascript:openExcelFile('t83_Kerrfinancialadvisorsinc/455X3/ExportActivity_66260230820190703122002139.xlsx  because it is not statc. Everyday a new file is generated so a new "Completed" button will appear on that page, with another ajavascript sentence @arunv

Comment: I think i am not correctly accessing the wanted elements using 
getElementsByTagName("main_table_data_right_border main_table_data_bottom_border")(5)
Do you know how to fix this ? Or expose another piece of code that would click on the first "Completed" word in this page?

Comment: then you can first extract the script name from webpage table using  ' .Innertext ' and then navigate that script or try using fire event method, if possible please share the url of webpage its hard to suggest without seeing that

Comment: Try using `debug.print  ie3.getelementbyId("idname").getElementsByTagName("tr")(index count).getElementsByTagName("td")(index).innertext`  or with different combinations to get "completed" text in immediate window you can self explore by trial and error

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but i am very new to VBA and i know nothing about javasript so i will not be able to figure this out by my own... I hope you understand. Can you give me more details about doing that or just type ou tthe sentence that has to be added to my code? I would be very thankfull

Answer (score 0):

I see you are a bit confused as to how to access HTML elements, so I'll take this opportunity to demonstrate the logic of doing so in a very detailed manner, which I also believe to be very intuitive. There are other ways to do it, but I believe the following one is the most comprehensive and intuitive one and ideal for a beginner.

Firstly, I will go ahead and assume that `ie3` is an `InternetExplorer` object.

When you use this object to navigate to a page, you can access the html of that page by using the `ie3.document`, which holds an `HTML document` object.

To take full advantage of the `HTML document` object you should add a reference to the `Microsoft HTML Object Library`. This Library will allow you to use a number of HTML elements which make your life easier.

In your case, the elements you want to be able to access are

1. HTML tables and their rows and cells
2. HTML anchor elements ()

So my declarations would be the following:

```
Dim ie3 As New InternetExplorer 'To be used to navigate to the page of interest
Dim doc As HTMLDocument 'this will hold the HTML document corresponding to the page
Dim toBeClicked As HTMLAnchorElement 'To be used to store the <a></a> element
Dim table As HTMLTable 'To be used to store the table element
Dim tableRow As HTMLTableRow 'To be used to store a row of the table element
Dim tableCell As HTMLTableCell 'To be used to store a cellof the table element
```

Assuming that you have already used the `ie3` to navigate to the website of interest, you can store it's HTML document in `doc` like so:

```
Set doc = ie3.document
```

Once you have access to the HTML document of the webpage, you can also get access to its elements in a number of ways, some more targeted than others. Below I am demonstrating the most common methods to do that, using the table element as an example.

1. If the table has a unique ID, you can get access to it by using the `.getElementById()` method. This method returns a single element. In your case, the table you're after, doesn't have an ID.
2. If the table belongs to a class, you can get access to it by using the `.getElementsByClassName()` method. This method returns a **collection** of elements, all of which belong to the same class. To get access to a member of this collection you can use a `(item index)` kind of notation. The first member has an index of `0`. In your case the table belongs to class `"advancedSearch_table"`, which happens to only have one member.
3. If there's no class or ID you can use the `.getElementsByTagName` method. This method returns a **collection** of all the elements who have the same tag. In your case you would need all the tables in the document. To get access to a member of this collection you can use a `(item index)` kind of notation. The first member has an index of `0`. Tags in HTML look like so `<tagName attribute="something">Something</tagName>`.

Below I demonstrate all three methods. You can use either one of the first two:

```
Set table = doc.getElementsByClassName("advancedSearch_table")(0)
Set table = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
Set table = doc.getElementById("ID of the table") 'only for demostration purposes, it doesn't apply to your case, as the table has no ID.
```

Keep in mind that in your case, there is only one table in the document and there's only one element that belongs to the class `"advancedSearch_table"`. This means that you need the first element of the corresponding collections. That's why I use `0` as index.

By the same logic as above, now that the table has been stored, you can get access to its rows and cells. More specifically, you need the 5th cell of the 4th row. That's where the link that you want to click is:

```
Set tableRow = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")(3)
Set tableCell = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")(4)
```

Finally, now that the cell of interest has been stored, you can access the anchor element and click it. Again, there's only one anchor element in the cell, so it's going to be the first one in the corresponding collection:

```
Set toBeClicked = tableCell.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
toBeClicked.Click
```

**BONUS**

If you want to click on all the "Completed" links, one by one, you need to loop through the corresponding elements. Here'w two ways to do it:

Click on the anchor in the 5th cell of each row:

```
For Each tableRow In table.Rows
    Set toBeClicked = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("td")(4).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    toBeClicked.Click
Next tableRow
```

Loop through all rows and though all cells of the table, find the inner text that you're looking for and click the corresponding anchor:

```
For Each tableRow In table.Rows
    For Each tableCell In tableRow.Cells
        If tableCell.innerText = "Something" Then
            Set toBeClicked = tableCell.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            toBeClicked.Click
    Next tableCell
Next tableRow
```